# How to store credentials in amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to access rest APIs of third party SaaS for that we will need to store login and password in AWS .

Where to store such sensitive information ?

Means when my code runs on EC2 it needs these credential to sign the request before sending to third party SaaS.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your EC2 instance is secured properly, which it pretty much is by default, and you limit who has access to it, (and don't accidentlly leave it exposed with weak passwords) there is no special requirements in EC2 about securing those credentials beyond what precautions you would take if you were not running them in EC2. For example, if you application was an .net application, I personally would feel comfortable storing those credentials right in the web.config or app.config.

AWS employees can't just randomly browse the data on your instance if that is what you are worred about.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Ec2 instance is virtually same as your own pc. Ensure the security of your Ec2 instance using security groups, this will ultimately protect your files in the Amazon Ec2 instance.

Your can store the credentials in any folder of Amazon ec2 as you intend, and use it during connection to saas api.